# Program stuck in socketRead0 method when requesting with OkHttp

Tags: java, twitter, connection, okhttp

I developed a Java library for Twitter API [here](https://github.com/redouane59/twittered) using OkHttp3 4.8.1.
Unfortunately, it looks like after having sent a request, once everything is finished, the program never stops and is stuck in `SocketInputStream`.
[image]

When not using cache, it is stuck in `waitForReferencePendingList` method of `Reference` class instead :
[image]

I tried everything, closing connection explicitly in my code like [this](https://github.com/redouane59/twittered/pull/61/files#diff-5eead23088fc62bd7155247ec6c890ccR61), updating the version of OkHttp, but still the same. Any idea ?

If needed, [here](https://github.com/redouane59/twittered/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/github/redouane59/twitter/helpers/RequestHelperV2.java#L33)  is the full code where the request is done, in summary :

```
      Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url(url)
          .get()
          .headers(Headers.of("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken))
          .build();
      OkHttpClient client     = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build()
      Response response       = client.newCall(request).execute();
      String   stringResponse = response.body().string();
      return Optional.ofNullable(TwitterClient.OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(stringResponse, classType));
```

Comment: Is there a class with a main method or similar that shows the actual problem?  The tests in the project pass?  Is there a particular problem url?

Comment: Does anything change when you call the close() method of the Response object?

Comment: @YuriSchimke in unit tests everything is ok, it looks like they force the program to close. 
My main class is in another project but it doesn't do anything more than calling one endpont like `User user = new TwitterClient().getUserFromUserName("RedouaneBali");`

Comment: @rmunge nothing change when calling the close(), the only change is when making the request with or without cache but in the two cases the program is stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Finally adding `client.connectionPool().evictAll();` elsewhere (in my post request to get a bearer token) solved the problem !